# Array Adapter is null after initialized (wrong layout file)

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

my app keeps crashing for a stupid reason! I have looked around and users with similar problems are using fragments, and I am using Activities. My code in the on create method is below.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_contact);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.device_name);

    ListView mPairedListView = findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
    mPairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
    mPairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        /* List of all paired devices */
        findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) {
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(mDevice.getName() + "\n" + mDevice.getAddress());
        }
    } else {
        /* No paired device */
        String mNoDevices = "None Paired";
```

The arror is as below,

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> ```
>
> android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
> null object reference
> at ca.edgarwideman.taxibuddy.ConnectPrinter.onCreate(ConnectPrinter.java:39)

and line number 39 (where the error occurs) is this,

```
mPairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
```

I got it , the answer is below...

Comment: That's saying your `ListView` is null. Can you include your `activity_select_contact.xml` layout file?

Comment: Just a moment will do

Comment: Dang it, that was my mistake, I was loading the wrong XML, wow I sure had my head in the sand!. Thanks for your help anyway! Guess thats what these forums are for! Chears!

Answer (score 1):

Got It! and I'm almost too embarrassed to admit it... Always make sure that your OnCreate starts the correct Layout file!

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_contact);
```

should be

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect_printer);
```

Thanks, guys for helping me out!
Credits to @ianhanniballake